# Remote Oracle database connection using java(netbeans)

Tags: java, oracle

This is the code that I use to connect with the Oracle database that is on my pc:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection co = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:etecsa", "system", "asd");
```

It works but if I change localhost for an ip it can not connect to the database. I already deactivated the firewall but nothing.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection co = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:10.8.6.50:1521:etecsa", "system", "asd");
```

Where can I configure the oracle database to accept the connection from a specific ip and not only from localhost?

Comment: "Where can I configure the oracle database to accept the connection from a specific ip and not only from localhost?"  Not sure what this means.  the ip/hostname in the connect string is the IP of the db service you wish to connect to.  So is there an oracle db running on 10.8.6.50?  If so, I would install the oracle client, and see if you can do a tnsping to the instance.  What error do you get when connecting with the 10.8.6.50 address?

Comment: maybe just a typo: ...:thin: **@** 10.8...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [documentation for DB URL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm#BEIJFHHB)

> jdbc:oracle:driver_type:[username/password]@database_specifier

so in your case (if **etecsa** is `SID`) the url will be `@host:port:SID`

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.8.6.50:1521:etecsa
```

if **etecsa** is a service name then use `@//host:port/service_name`

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.8.6.50:1521/etecsa
```

Comment: I tried with that but it does not work. This is the error that gives java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection